# Get lattest version of rails installed how

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have version  18.04.03 lts of ubuntu but I am trying to install version  5 at least of rails but every time I get 4.2.10 version number I need to be able to use the credential manager which is only availed in 5 greater than version.

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: @dan-klasson i upgraded unbuntu to 19 i was use apt-get install

Comment: use bundler instead

Comment: @dan-klasson thanks for the tip

Comment: that will help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04